# Electronic facial massage machine and bigger music instrument as a carry-on luggage?

Tags: luggage

[image]

Is this allowed to bring on flight as a carry-on luggage? Its size is like an electronic toothbrush.

[image]

And this is the instrument (quite long).

I will fly with SAS airline in a business class, normally I'm allowed to bring 2 of 23kg luggages, but I prefer to take my instrument al a carry-on luggage.

Comment: These are two completely separate questions, which should be asked separately: Stack Exchange questions are meant to be useful to people other than just the person who asked them and it seems unlikely that many people will have the same combination of items as you. However, the two individual questions are both perfectly reasonable on their own. Having said that, there must be a huge amount of advice on this site and elsewhere on the internet about how to carry large musical instruments on planes: it's not at all unusual. Surely that part is a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: That facial massage machine is like an electronic razor and should have zero problems: batteries are no problem (this small anyways), it is not a liquid, it's not sharp, it is not flammable or explosive.